# Comparing Sequential Patterns between Two Columns - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I started with a dataframe that did not include a timestamp column. My goal is to create one. All I know is that the rows are sorted ascending in time, and that the minimum first day could be 2008-01-01 or later, and the maximum last day could be 2010-11-30. Rows represent events that may or may not have occurred in the same day. So there might be multiple rows for a given day.

Luckily, this dataframe includes a daily euribor3m rate column, so assuming each time the rate value changes we have a new day, I used a row by row comparison and only kept rows where a change in value occurred. Now, this is not perfect because technically two sequential days might have the same rate value, but it's close enough. I created a new df called res with the subset of rows.

Then, I downloaded a separate file with the actual euribor3m rate from a different source. This file includes a timestamp and has no nulls or missing days. I filtered rows for the date ranges I mentioned above. So my goal now is to join and apply the timestamp to the original file.

Here is the catch: I cannot simply do a join because the res dataframe might skip certain days and/or the same rate might have occurred for multiple days in a row (as mentioned above). However, doing a head() and tail() comparison between the two dataframes, the patterns are very close.

So my question is: how do I match these two dataframes based on the rate values, knowing that the res dataframe might skip certain days, and knowing that I cannot match on the single values as keys? Is there perhaps a way to match on a pattern, such as taking x rows from the res dataframe euribor3m rate, and just matching the second file with x rows based on the sequence and discarding values in between (which would reflect days that were not reported in the original file?)

```
#Original DF:

res['euribor3m'].tail(10)
41108    1.048
41123    1.046
41129    1.044
41138    1.041
41148    1.040
41157    1.039
41164    1.035
41170    1.030
41178    1.031
41187    1.028
Name: euribor3m, dtype: float64

#Second file DF: 
#Notice the value column is the euribor 3m rate

euribor_daily_df.tail(10)
            Date         Value
2074    2010-11-16  1.046
2073    2010-11-17  1.044
2072    2010-11-18  1.041
2071    2010-11-19  1.040
2070    2010-11-22  1.039
2069    2010-11-23  1.035
2068    2010-11-24  1.030
2067    2010-11-25  1.031
2066    2010-11-26  1.028
2065    2010-11-29  1.027
```

Comment: perhaps you could use `merge` - that way you will get an output the size of the larger df, with `NaN` values where an exact match isn't found

Comment: @JoshFriedlander thank you for your reply. Wouldn’t that be essentially a left outer join?

Comment: correct, I just figured this way you'd have a record of anywhere rows were absent from either table...I may well have misunderstood your question

Comment: wouldn't merge only work if there are no duplicates in the 'Value' column?